# Nitrous.io: Are there any docs for autoparts package development

Tags: ruby, nitrousio

I'm developing a package for nitrous.io autoparts and wonder if there is any documentation or resources for package developers.

My main problem is that autoparts is not very verbose. It's just telling me that a command failed but not why it failed or the output of that command. Is there a way to increase the verbosity? Log files? Anything?

Additionally, it's behaviour is really strange, see that gist: https://gist.github.com/phortx/9504396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Autoparts documentation has been updated to include package development information. Here are a couple guides to help you out.

Guidelines and contribution instructions: https://github.com/nitrous-io/autoparts/blob/master/docs/contributing.md

Example part: https://github.com/nitrous-io/autoparts/blob/master/docs/example-part.rb

You can also view the documentation within your Nitrous.IO box by running the following commands within the console. You may need to run `$ parts update` in the console first to pull the latest documentation.

```
$ cat ~/.parts/autoparts/docs/contributing.md
$ cat ~/.parts/autoparts/docs/example-part.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I still not found docs, but found solutions for my problems. Actually parts is verbose, it crashes before any output. The reason for that crash which I also showed in my gist is that it can't extract `.xz` files.